# Unable to download file in Heroku using rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have controller and a action method called download, here is the code snippet 
    def download
    send_file Rails.root.join('public', 'abc.pdf'), :type=>"application/pdf", :x_sendfile=>true
    end
And in my view, I have link as follows
    <%= link_to 'Download Full CV', {:action => :download}, :class => "btn btn-primary btn-md" %>

Everything works just fine in my DEV but after moving to heroku its not working

I have tried modifying production.rb as follows but no luck 
    config.serve_static_assets = true

Can anyone help me on this, by the way the file is located in public folder and I am precompiling assets locally before moving to heroku

Comment: Are you sure the pdf file was deployed to Heroku?

Comment: Ah silly me, I did git commit -am "comment" followed by git push thinking that it will move everything to git but it doesn't, not sure why this happened. so now i did git add . then gitt commit then got push. Now everything is pushed, thanks a lot. it was a silly mistake.

Comment: No prob, I do it all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone else needs this, verify the file was pushed to Heroku.  If you are using a .slugignore file that ignores pdf's, this may also be the problem.